# CNTK error: Did not find a valid input name at offset 201303500 in the input file

Tags: cntk

I am trying to read SVHN dataset using CNTK CTFDeserializer. SVHN dataset is a .mat dataset. So I am using scipy.io.loadmat to load them and trying to modify https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_103A_MNIST_DataLoader.ipynb for read the data, flatten it and store it as txt. and https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_201B_CIFAR-10_ImageHandsOn.ipynb to read and reshape the txt file and run the CNN model.

It is throwing me "Did not find a valid input name at offset 201303500 in the input file" error.

My txt file is in the following format for 73257 times.
|labels 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |features 33 30 for (3*32*32 times)

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably happening near the end of the file (maybe not all output was flushed to the file?). To figure out what goes wrong write a subset of the data to the file and manually inspect the end of the file. Searching through the codebase for the error did not yield any results, but I can update this answer if you provide a precise error message.

Another possibility if you have the dataset already as numpy arrays is to just slice off minibatches and feed it to cntk yourself. CNTK tutorials 104 and 106 show how to do this.